# What does "week" mean in place names?

Tags: meaning, names

I visited darkest Devon recently, and happened to pass through a couple of places named "Week". On studying the map I found several others, such as James Week, Mary Week, Chawleigh Week, and so on.

Does "Week" had a special meaning in place names, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it means a "specialised farm" in most of the uses in Devon.  From the Old English *wic*, which just means a settlement, village or dwelling.

Comment: Here's a link that seems to corroborate this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeks_(surname)#Derivation

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Thanks for that. The second derivation listed there, a variant of *Wick*, is the one in question.  Note it talks of an outlying farm or works.

Comment: This -wic is also the same root that gives us Norwich and Sandwich, etc. When I took Old English we were taught to pronounce it with the "ch" sound. It varied, though: the city of York used to be called Eoforwic, pronounced something like "Ayowvorwick" — how they got to York would make an interesting study in itself.

Comment: @Robusto: Well the root seems to be *-wic* in the north, *-week* in the southwest and *-wich* in the east.  The regions do have quite different linguistic influences pre-conquest, it would be interesting to know exactly why the differences.  I would love to have learned Old English, quite jealous!

Comment: In Old English generally, 'c' before or after front-vowels tended to palatalise to (the sound we now write) 'ch', as in many other languages. In the Danelaw (North and East England), there was an influx of Danish words which were often very similar to the English ones, but did not have this palatalisation. So "kirk" vs "cirice" (=> "church") and "skirt" vs "shirt". "Vik" is seen in many Scandinavian (and Icelandic) names still. Why the vowel was lengthened in the Southwest I don't know.

Comment: "York" has a very interesting history. Celtic "Eborac(on)" (from a root meaning "thorn-tree", IIRC) was folk-etymologised by the Anglo-Saxons to "Eoforwic" = "Boar-stead". That name was borrowed by the Danes, who rendered the English "wic" as their "vik" as elsewhere, but couldn't make any sense of the "Eofor", so it came out as "Jorvik" (where the "J" is pronounced "y"). In time this got reduced to York.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Wonderful information, thanks for that.  I've always loved York city.  I visited the city for a week as a child whilst researching the Danelaw at school and was enthralled with the history.

Comment: Thank you for that, Orbling. Most interesting, as is the discussion that followed.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: Quite alright, the ensuing conversation was substantially more interesting than my initial sentence, so the thanks is shared.

Comment: Thank you. I ought to have checked, rather than (mis-)remembering.